# Ruby Yard: documenting a parameter that accept multiple types

Tags: ruby, typescript

I'm migrating and documenting an old Ruby (specifically Sketchup) code base but I'm not very familiar with the ecosystem. Since I'm more used to TypeScript, I'm asking what is the equivalent documentation of this in Ruby:

```js
function get_definition(instance: ComponentInstance | Group | Image)
```

I've tried this:

```rb
# @param [ComponentInstance | Group | Image] instance
def self.get_definition(instance)
```

but I'm unsure if this is correct.

Comment: Why not consult the [documentation](https://rubydoc.info/gems/yard/file/docs/GettingStarted.md#declaring-types)? Multiple types are separated by `,` not `|`.

Comment: Thanks, I actually did check the docs but I was so focused on the Tags overview part and haven't read all of the docs, and also google brought up misleading results when I tried to search for that, but thanks anyway.

Answer (score 2):

### Some Possible YARD Tag Examples for Your Code

> def self.get_definition(instance)

There really isn't enough of your code to be sure what the real programmer intent is, so you'll have to adapt a bit as needed. Additionally, it's important to understand that YARD tags are really just *documentation*, not enforced contracts or even type definitions in the sense of [RBS](https://github.com/ruby/rbs), which can be used to create typed signatures that can be checked with various external utilities.

Since you are defining your own objects, you probably want to use the [Class or Module Types](https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/yard/file/docs/Tags.md#class-or-module-types) tag, with or without sub-types. For example, assuming the *instance* argument can be any of three completely different classes:

```rb
# Class or module method to return the definition of an
# object.
#
# @param instance [ComponentInstance, Group, Image] a single
#   injected object of one of the listed classes
# @return [Array<String>] components that define _instance_
def self.get_definition(instance)
end
```

On the other hand, if Group and Image classes inherit from ComponentInstance, or perhaps are contained by one, then you might use the following instead:

```rb
# Class or module method that uses a ComponentInstance to create
# side effects.
#
# @param instance [ComponentInstance<Group, Image>] an injected
#   ComponentInstance object holding one or more Group or Image
#   objects
# @return [void] because we don't care about the return value,
#   just the side effects
def self.get_definition(instance)
end
```

You might also benefit from duck-typing, where you don't care what the *instance* object actually is, so long as it conforms to a given API. For example:

```rb
# Class or module method to return the definition of a
# serialized object.
#
# @param instance [#define, #inspect, #ancestors] object that
#   will #respond_to? one of the listed methods
# @return [String<JSON>] a definition String that has been
#   serialized as JSON for consumption by an API
def self.get_definition(instance)
end
```

There are certainly other tags and macros you might use, depending on the semantics you want to convey, but that should get you started. You might also want to look at [RBS](https://github.com/ruby/rbs) or [TypeProf](https://github.com/ruby/typeprof) if you need real signature delcarations, or if you're planning to use some sort of third-party typing system with your code, e.g. [Steep](https://github.com/soutaro/steep) or [Sorbet](https://sorbet.org/). For documentation, though, plain [RDoc](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-3.1.2/libdoc/rdoc/rdoc/RDoc.html) or [YARD tags](https://yardoc.org/) with RDoc or Markdown are generally your best bets.